# Is it possible to open solution view and folder view at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I often need to switch back and forth between solution view and folder view to access files that are not added to solution files (because I want to keep those files' real folder structure and not manually add/remove those files to solution).

It would be very convenient to have open both at the same time (e.g. by having two solution explorer windows where one of them is in folder view mode). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. I've tried this myself: you can open two solution explorers at the same time and open Solution View in one pane and Folder View in the other. However, Visual Studio operates only in one of two contexts, meaning that the menu-items and toolbar buttons are geared towards only one of the two views. For example, once I created the second solution explorer and navigated to Folder View, I could no longer build my solution, even if I selected the Solution View in the other pane.

So, technically it is possible, but functionally it doesn't work like you would expect. It would be awesome if MS implemented this feature later on, because I think many people would like to be able to work like this.